# Prove $\mu=\sum_{n}\alpha_n\delta_{x_n}$ is a Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure iff $\sum_{n:|x_n|\leq K}\alpha_n<\infty$.

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to prove $\mu=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\alpha_n\delta_{x_n}$ is a Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure for a given dist. function F iff $\sum_{n:|x_n|\leq K}\alpha_n<\infty$ for all $K>0$, where $\delta_{x_n}$ is the Dirac function at $x_n$.

Here's my try.

$\rightarrow$ direction:

for all $K>0$, $\mu([-K,K])=\mu(\{-K\})+\mu((-K,K])=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\alpha_n\delta_{x_n}(\{-K\})+F(K)-F(-K)$ My problem here, is that I can't get rid of $\mu(\{-K\})$ since we could get the case that $\mu(\{-K\})=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\alpha_n$. I had $\mu([-K,K])<\infty$, then $\sum_{n:|x_n|\leq K}\alpha_n=\mu([-K,K])<\infty$

$\leftarrow$ direction:

If $x\geq 0$ then $F(x)=\sum_{n;x_n \in [0,x]}\alpha_n$, otherwise $F(x)=-\sum_{n;x_n \in (x,0)}\alpha_n$. Then we have $\mu((a,b])=F(b)-F(a)<\infty$. The problem here is that how would I prove that the $F$ is increasing or even right-continuous...

Am I on the right track? Any advice on how to solve the problems with my 'proof'?

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to add the condition that $\alpha_n\geq 0$ for all $n$. Then, it's very easy to prove that F, as defined above, is increasing and right-continuous.

For the other direction, $\mu(\{-K\})\leq \mu((-K-1,-K)<\infty$, by monotony of the measure.